# What is the version specified in header of GIMP app? e.g. 1.0 or 2.0

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, gimp

When I open the single channel mask image in GIMP, I am seeing some sort of version specified in header as:

[image]

I am on ubuntu linux and see this value change during my 2 different mask files. One of them says 1.0, while other one says 2.0.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

It is not a version. It is actually the image object ID in Gimp, followed by a Display sequence number. For instance in this setup:

[image]

You see that

- `Image1` (the one with a "1" drawn in it) has id `3`
- `Image3` (the one with a "3" drawn in it) has id `4`
- `Image2` (the one with a "2" drawn in it) has id `2`
- `Image2` has two views, which is why one view is `2.0` while the other is `2.1`.

Image IDs are allocated in sequence starting from 1 (yes, I loaded and closed another image before doing the screenshot). Display sequence numbers are a sequence for the image different from the Display object ID.

When you code in script-fu, you handle the image IDs directly,but when you use python-fu (as I did) this ID is a mere attribute of the `gimp.Image` object and you almost never use it. Normally your code cannot interact with displays it did not create itself (using `gimp.Display(image)`).